# Injecting DB class into the __constructor variable inside an Abstract Class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Unable to inject Laravel's DB class into an abstract class located in another namespace folder.

Getting Error **"Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::table()"**

---

-Check:Working-
**FrontController.php**

```
<?php
use MyProject\MainPages\Front;

    class indexController extends \BaseController {

        /**
         * @var Front
         */
        private $Front;

        /**
         * @param ProductRepository $productRepo
         */
        function __construct(Front $Front)
        {
            //Test 
            //$this->Front = $Front->goSetup();
        }
    }
```

---

-Check:Working-
**Front.php**

```
<?php namespace MyProject\MainPages;

use MyProject\MainPages\NavigationSkeleton;

class Front extends NavigationBluPrint {

    /**
     * Begins the process, Step 1
     */
    protected function goSetup() {
        // $this->DB->table() etc
    }
}
```

---

-Not Working-
**NavigationBluPrint.php**

```
<?php namespace MyProject\MainPages;

use \DB;

abstract class NavigationBluPrint {

    /**
     * @var DB Laravel Database connection
     */
    protected $dB;

    public function __construct(DB $dB)
    {
        // SetDB so when extended it's already set for extended classes
        $this->dB = $dB;
        // Test below
        $x = $this->dB->table('products')->get(); //Error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::table()
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($x);
        echo '<pre>';
    }
}
```

---

If I need to do something with App:: to make this work, I dont understand how it's done. Thank you

---

Solution Found:In case someone else runs into the same problem.

In abstract class "NavigationBluPrint.php"

I replaced \DB; with=> use \Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager as DB;

It seems to fix the problem, although I'm not sure whether its instantiating a new DB from start or using the same one. If former then it kind of defeats the purpose.

Comment: I believe that the ```use``` effect does only affect the script in which it's declared. If you include, require or extend from a script that had ```use```, it doesn't work. You should try using the full namespace for anything pertaining the DB class.

Comment: @amenadiel That's the reason I wanted to use an abstract class so I wouldn't have to declare it each time. Is there any other way while still staying in the same abstract class?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Laravel, but it doesn't seem that bad to use \DB instead of DB. It's a root class, isn't it?

Comment: @amenadiel I'm new to Laravel myself, from what I understand it's native to Laravel using "Facades", for root I guess. I was hoping to inject the database into the abstract class and extend it to the classes in that namespace that will be using the Blueprint to also have DB. If I ever change my DB then I won't have to update it in 10 different places in MyProject namespace, and instead only in one location. Thank for trying though

Comment: You can still do that. Just remove use DB and inject the DB with its fully qualyfied namespace.

Comment: @amenadiel Just tried both namespaces directly that were listed in the facade, neither one worked. use \Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager;
use \Illuminate\Database\Connection;

Answer (score 0):

You're type hinting the facade for the DB class, not the DB class itself.

Comment: I'm just beginning to pick up Laravel this week. How would you go about accessing DB itself, Calling it by direct namespace, App::bind? I won't be using Eloquent, but I will be using the DB class

Comment: It seems the full classname is \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB

Answer (score 0):

It's false the idea of using static method, via object and it is impossible.

you should create repository for your database operation then you can inject them greatly.

directions to create Eloquent repository or DB repository :

Here I found out a [great article](http://culttt.com/2013/07/08/creating-flexible-controllers-in-laravel-4-using-repositories/) to do this.

Comment: Sorry for late reply signed in today. I read the article you linked plus few more on repositories. I got the jest of it. Still just a little confused Example- CarRepositoryInterface file will be linked from the controller, and the the CarRepositoryInterface file with be app binded to the actual CarRepository file. Where will I inject the DB into, and how? Plus I need the model class to Manipulate/Play around with the DB data I just retrieved before I dish it back out to the controller. Will the DB connection be saved in CarRepository file? How will my CarModel class get that injected into it?